# How to to read tuple dynamically named in command line argument (sys.argv)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to to read tuple dynamically named in command line argument (sys.argv) ?

Below example doesn’t work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
cmd1 = sys.argv[1]
tpl1 = ('one', 'two', 'three')
tpl2 = ('four', 'five', 'six')
print (cmd1)
val1 = cmd1[0]
val2 = cmd1[1]
val3 = cmd1[2]
print (val1)
print (val2)
print (val3)
```

current output for **script.py tpl1** :

```
t
p
l
```

desired output for **script.py tpl1** :

```
one
two
three
```

Please advise, thanks

Comment: If you do `script.py tpl1`, then `cmd1 = sys.argv[1] == "tpl1"`, so doing `cmd1[0]` is the same as doing `"tpl1"[0]` which is `"t"`. How is this surprising?

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Question is how would I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary, accessing variables using strings is almost never a good idea.

```
d = {
      'tpl1': ('one', 'two', 'three'),
      'tpl2': ('four', 'five', 'six')
    }

cmd1 = sys.argv[1]
print (d[cmd1])
```

Comment: If I use this how would I assign values from tuple to particular variables? i.e. command line argument = name of the tuple, but val1 = first value from tuple... val2 = second value from tuple etc

Comment: Answer: val1 = (d[cmd1])[0]

Comment: @user3281086 Looking for a generalized answer to this problem will probably lead you to `exec` or `eval`. [Take a look at this explanation of what they do and why it's dangerous to treat user input like code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) just preemptively